# Store Bootstrap Data - Modal, Badges and Alerts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following lines of code in my web page - [example/demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doLVzR?editors=101).

```js
 

/* Messages Modal */
$(document).ready(function(){
    var informer = $("#messageInformer a");
    var refreshBadge = function(messageCount) {
        var badge = informer.find(".badge");
        
        if (messageCount > 0) {
            if (!badge.length) {
                informer.text("Messages ");
                informer.append("<span class=\"badge\">" + messageCount + "</span>");
            } 
            
            else {
                badge.text(messageCount);
            }
        } 
        
        else {
            // informer.text("No messages");
            informer.text("Messages ");
            informer.append("<span class=\"badge\">" + messageCount + "</span>");
        }
    };

    var buildMessage = function(message) {
        var htmlMessage = "<div class=\"alert fade in\">";
        
        htmlMessage += "<a href=\"#\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-lable=\"close\" data-id=\"" + message.id + "\">&times;</a>";
        htmlMessage += "<strong>" + message.title + "</strong>";
        htmlMessage += "<p>" + message.text + "</p>";
        
        return htmlMessage;
    }

    // Messages To Display
    var messages = [
        { 
         id: "1", 
         title: "Title 01:",
          text: "<ul> \
          <li>List Item</li> \
          <li>List Item</li> \
          </ul> \
          <br/> \
  <p>Paragraph</p> \
  <p>E-Mail: <a href=\"mailto:email@address.com\">email@address.com</a></p> \
         " 
        },
        { 
         id: "2", 
         title: "Title 02:", 
         text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam volutpat velit et vehicula vulputate." 
        },
        { 
         id: "3", 
         title: "Title 03:", 
         text: "Quisque viverra nisl ut arcu eleifend aliquam. Ut faucibus efficitur nibh, sit amet tincidunt est volutpat non." 
        }
    ];

    refreshBadge(messages.length);

    informer.on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var modalBody = $(".modal-body");
        modalBody.empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            modalBody.append(buildMessage(messages[i]));
        }
        
        if (messages.length == 0) {
            $('.modal-body').text('There are no more messages to display.');
        }
    });

    $("body").delegate(".alert .close", "click", function() {
        var messageId = $(this).data("id");
        // AJAX 
        messages = messages.filter(function(el) {
            return el.id != messageId;
        });
        
        if (messages.length == 0) {
            // $("#messagesModal").modal("hide");
            $('.modal-body').text('There are no more messages to display.');
        }
        
        refreshBadge(messages.length);
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<p data-toggle="modal" data-target="#messagesModal" id="messageInformer"><a href="#">Messages <span class="badge"></span></a>
</p>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="messagesModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Messages</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="col-md-8 pull-left">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I store the data of the modal, badge and alerts when the page is refreshed?

For example, if you remove one of the three messages and then refresh the page, only two messages should then be available.

Comment: I'd use a [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or cookie

Comment: I'm not very familiar with using `localStorage` and how I would go about, or which lines I am suppose to modify to get this to work in my project.  If you could kindly provide a working example, that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not gonna edit my answer because above answer for sample purpose who wanna implement `sessionStorage`. Here I am gonna solve your specific problem so posting another code so that your problem can be resolve.

we are implementing `sessionStorage` technique to manage already remove elements which works in a single tab. 
For testing purpose I am not setting any fiddle for it so you just need to copy code and set it on local environment.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var informer = $("#messageInformer a");
    var refreshBadge = function(messageCount) {
        var badge = informer.find(".badge");

        if (messageCount > 0) {
            if (!badge.length) {
                informer.text("Messages ");
                informer.append("<span class=\"badge\">" + messageCount + "</span>");
            } 

            else {
                badge.text(messageCount);
            }
        } 

        else {
            // informer.text("No messages");
            informer.text("Messages ");
            informer.append("<span class=\"badge\">" + messageCount + "</span>");
        }
    };

    var buildMessage = function(message) {
        var htmlMessage = "<div class=\"alert fade in\">";

        htmlMessage += "<a href=\"javascript:;\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-lable=\"close\" data-id=\"" + message.id + "\" onclick='deleteIds(this)'>&times;</a>";
        htmlMessage += "<strong>" + message.title + "</strong>";
        htmlMessage += "<p>" + message.text + "</p>";

        return htmlMessage;
    }

    // Messages To Display
    var messages = [
        { 
            id: "1", 
            title: "Title 01:",
            text: "<ul> \
            <li>List Item</li> \
            <li>List Item</li> \
            </ul> \
            <br> \
        <p>Paragraph</p> \
        <p>E-Mail: <a href=\"mailto:email@address.com\">email@address.com</a></p> \
            " 
        },
        { 
            id: "2", 
            title: "Title 02:", 
            text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam volutpat velit et vehicula vulputate." 
        },
        { 
            id: "3", 
            title: "Title 03:", 
            text: "Quisque viverra nisl ut arcu eleifend aliquam. Ut faucibus efficitur nibh, sit amet tincidunt est volutpat non." 
        }
    ];


    removeDeletedItem(messages);

    refreshBadge(messages.length);

    informer.on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var modalBody = $(".modal-body");
        modalBody.empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            modalBody.append(buildMessage(messages[i]));
        }

        if (messages.length == 0) {
            $('.modal-body').text('There are no more messages to display.');
        }
    });

    $("body").delegate(".alert .close", "click", function() {
        var messageId = $(this).data("id");
        // AJAX 
        messages = messages.filter(function(el) {
            return el.id != messageId;
        });

        if (messages.length == 0) {
            // $("#messagesModal").modal("hide");
            $('.modal-body').text('There are no more messages to display.');
        }

        refreshBadge(messages.length);
    });
});

function deleteIds(obj){
    var currentId = $(obj).attr('data-id');
    var id = sessionStorage.getItem("id");

    if(id == null){
        sessionStorage.setItem("id", currentId);
    }else{
        var str = id.split(',').join();
        str = str + ','+ currentId
        sessionStorage.setItem("id", str);
    }
    $(obj).parent().hide();
}

function removeDeletedItem(obj){
    var id = sessionStorage.getItem("id");
    if(id != null){
        var temp = id.split(',');   
        $.each(temp, function(index, value){

                var i = -1;
            $.each(obj, function(ind,val){
                if(val.id == value)
                i = ind;
            });

            if(i != -1){
                obj.splice(i,1);
            }
        });
    }
}

</script>
<body>
<p data-toggle="modal" data-target="#messagesModal" id="messageInformer"><a href="#">Messages <span class="badge"></span></a>
</p>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="messagesModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Messages</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="col-md-8 pull-left">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI I added two function in your code `deleteIds` and `removeDeletedItem`

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement either `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` for your page.

`localStorage` - stores data with no expiration date

`sessionStorage` - stores data for one session (data is lost when the browser tab is closed)

Here instead of editing your code I am just posting sample code for your help through which u can do your desire task.

You just need to follow the logical concept from below code and implement in your code.

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src=" http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    var id = sessionStorage.getItem("id");
    if(id != null){
        var temp = id.split(',');   
        $.each(temp, function(index, value){
                        $('#'+value).hide();
        });
    }
});

function deleteItem(obj, object){

var id = sessionStorage.getItem("id");

if(id == null){
    sessionStorage.setItem("id", obj);
}else{
    var str = id.split(',').join();
    str = str + ','+ obj
    sessionStorage.setItem("id", str);
}
$(object).parent().hide();
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<h2 id="1">Header 1 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:;" onclick="deleteItem('1', this)">X</a></h2>
<h2 id="2">Header 2 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:;" onclick="deleteItem('2', this)">X</a></h2>
<h2 id="3">Header 3 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:;" onclick="deleteItem('3', this)">X</a></h2>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To be honest, it's still a little bit confusing for me.  I haven't had any formal training in coding/programming - but from what I've gathered, I need to use either `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` with an `if` statement and then somehow attach it to the `id` of each element I want to store.  I'm still working at it with a bit of trial and error, but your help so far is much appreciated.

Comment: Still no luck. Would it be possible for you to use the code that I have provided in my original post instead, so that I can see where I am going wrong?

Comment: @user1752759 give me some time I am editing your code and will post ASAP