# How to remember a form is extended?

Tags: javascript, jquery, session

I have a multistep form in my project, the first step of which has a javascript extend field function where a user can add additional fields. If the user goes to the next step, the data is of course stored in Session until final submission. However,  the extended form will not be remembered. If the user goes back from next step the additional field and its data is not displayed, worse still, if the data in the additional field is invalid, the user won't see it, as the message is displayed underneath the disappeared field (I'm using Cakephp default validation).

Is there a way, like storing the setting in session, to make it stay?

```js
var counter = 0;
function moreFields(val1, val2, val3) {
 counter++;
 var newField = document.getElementById(val1).cloneNode(true);
 newField.id = '';
 newField.style.display = 'block';
 var newFields = newField.querySelectorAll('[name], [id], [for], [data-display]');
  for (var i=0;i<newFields.length;i++) {
   var theNames = newFields[i].name
   if (theNames)
    newFields[i].name = "data[" + val3 + "][" + counter + "][" + theNames + "]";
   var theNames2 = newFields[i].id;
         if (theNames2)
             newFields[i].id = theNames2 + counter;
          console.log(newFields[i].id); 
         var theNames3 = newFields[i].htmlFor;
         if (theNames3)
             newFields[i].htmlFor = theNames3 + counter;
          //console.log(newFields[i].htmlFor);  
      var theNames4 = newFields[i].dataset.display;
         if (theNames4)
             newFields[i].dataset.display = theNames4 + counter;
          console.log(newFields[i].dataset.display);   
  }   
 var insertHere = document.getElementById(val2);
 insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newField,insertHere);
}
```

```html
<span id="readroot" style="display: none">
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="form-group required">
            <label for="Student1Grade">Grade</label>
            <select name="grade" data-display="#display_student_1_grade" class="form-control" id="Student1Grade" required="required">
                <option value="">Please Select</option>
                <option value="1">Grade 1</option>
                <option value="1">Grade 2</option>
            </select>
        </div>      
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Student1Gender">Gender</label>      
            <select name="gender" data-display="#display_student_1_gender" class="form-control" id="Student1Gender">
                <option value="1">Male</option>
                <option value="2">Female</option>
            </select>
        </div>
 </div> 
</div>
<input class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Remove" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);" /><br /><br />
</span>
<span id="writeroot"></span>  
<input class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="moreFields('readroot', 'writeroot', 'Student')" value="Add Field" />
```

Comment: are you store  additional fields details along with data in session before go to next step ?

Comment: Yes. All the data is saved in session every step, typical multistep form approach.  But as a user returns, the additional field disappears and even if the user clicks 'add field' again, the ids of the new additional field may not be the same.

Comment: if we save data in browser session then it would be good for you ?????

Comment: I hope the browser to remember that the user has added additional fields and make them stay, so when the user goes back from the next step or is stopped by validation when he/she hits 'Next', the additional field will not just disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement either sessionStorage or localStorage for your page.

`localStorage` - stores data with no expiration date

`sessionStorage` - stores data for one session (data is lost when the browser tab is closed)

Here I am just posting sample code for your help through which u can do your desire task. You just need to follow the logical concept from below code and implement in your code.

There is a sample also which is only containing `id` but you can implement it in other way which can full fill  your task.

[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31988819/store-bootstrap-data-modal-badges-and-alerts/32004214#32004214)

Comment: if u having problem to modify your code then u can ask any time

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I need. However.. may I be cheeky to ask for more hints? I've tried to adapt your code to my needs but, I can't figure out much. If a form is cloned, I can assign a unique id to it, and save it along with all the associated incremented field ids to sessionStorage. But then if sessionStorage returns true that the ids exist, say the user created two forms, do I set the moreFields() to run cloning method twice again automatically? 

Could you advise more on how I can go about it? Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes I am having problem to modify it...... been thinking for an hour trying.. I really do not want to bother you further but...

Comment: first get variable from sessionStrorage then check that it is null.... if null that means you didn't set any data and you need to set variable with a unique name now if you didn't get null means you already set values for this unique variable now you can append new form data with it and when you need then u can cross check for elements

Comment: I understand the 'check id if null' bit, but I don't know what do I do when it did return a value, do I set the function to automatically clone a form? don't know if it helps, Im trying to do [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/domform.html)

Comment: Just thought I'd ask.. could you be so kind to provide an example based on the codes in the post/from the above website? I'm still trying but in vain..

Comment: The sessionStorage problem is a bit tricky in my case. I can't just save all the (ids of) extended forms the user created, because some of them may be removed by the user. I should only save those that the user are actually saving as he/she clicks 'next step'.

Comment: Am I right to say that I should create a onClick function for the 'next step' button and save all the final ids of the extended form/forms to sessionStorage, and check at the beginning of the html document to see if any ids exists in sessionStorage, and if there is, I trigger the cloneNode method by default and instead of assigning new ids for the fields as it's cloned, I assign the stored ids back? Still, I'm not sure how exactly it can be done...

Comment: set fiddle of your code so that we can run it here and implement code here or at local

Comment: somehow I always failed to make the extend form work in Jsfiddle, but I created a js snippet in the post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87008/discussion-between-alvin-mok-and-dom).